# Как реализовать работу очередей Laravel на Windows Server

Tags: laravel, очередь, windows-server

Пытаюсь реализовать работу очередей Laravel на Windows Server.

Проблема следующая:

запускаю несколько экземпляров обработчиков очередей через командную строку:

`php artisan queue:work --queue=CopyToMainServer`

процесс работает какое-то время, после падает.
Пытался запихнуть в планировщик заданий, но оттуда вообще очередь не запускается.

Есть ли возможность каким-либо образом реализовать нормальную работу очередей Laravel на Windows Server без использования стороннего ПО?